# Need help with integral involving square root (definite or indefinite version)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to find an analytical solution for this problem:

$ \int_{-a/2}^{a/2}\frac{z}{z^{2}+(x-x')^{2}}\frac{sx'-y}{\sqrt{z^{2}+(x-x')^{2}+\left(sx'-y\right)^{2}}}dx'
$

where $x$, $y$, $z$, $a$ and $s$ are constants (all real). and I can't figure out the way to do it. I tried the following change of variable without success:

$x' = x + \tan u \sqrt{\left(sx'-y\right)^2 + z^2}$

can you please help with the change of variable, or the solution to the indefinite integral (if my approach is not on the right track) so that I can calculate the above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematica gives a complicated results for

$\int \frac{z}{z^{2}+(x-t)^{2}}
      \frac{st-y}
           {z^{2}+(x-t)^{2}+(st-y)^{2}} dt$

[image]

and
$\int_{-\frac{a}{2}}^{\frac{a}{2}}
   \frac{z}{z^{2}+(x-t)^{2}}
   \frac{st-y}
        {z^{2}+(x-t)^{2}+(st-y)^{2}} dt$

[image]

Comment: Hi Ng, thank you for your answer. Yes, I tried that approach also, and I was even trying to simplify that for a day or so. The main thing with that is the fact that complex numbers are present in the solution and I guess that they are not needed at all. In fact, complex number appear in that solution but they vanish at the end. I do however think there is a simpler (not necessarily simple )analytical solution to this problem. But thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Yes, the result is so complicated that the machine retains the complex form.  If you specify the values of $x, y, z$  and $s$,  you may use $\ln (x+yi) = \ln \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}+i\tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}$ to simplify your work.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify that all those constants, including $a$ are real numbers. Let me add that I find your answer useful and I already up-voted it, but since I am new here it will only be seen later when and if I have 15 reputations. I will erase this part of my comment later, but I wanted you to know that.